# One-line assignment of struct

Tags: c

I know I can do this:

```
VALUE val2 = {.value = "new", .type = STRING};
```

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
VALUE * val2 = malloc(sizeof(VALUE)) {.value = "new", .type = STRING}
```

If not, what would be the closest to it?

Comment: No. You cannot allocate with `malloc` and initialize in the same call. You can do `VALUE tmp = {.value = "new", .type = STRING};` then `VALUE * val2 = malloc(sizeof(VALUE));` (don't forget to check the return) and then do `*val2 = tmp;` to fill `val2`.

Comment: No, you can't do the dynamic memory allocation and initialization in one line like that. You'd have to do `VALUE *val2 = malloc(sizeof(*val2)); *val2 = (VALUE) { .value = "new", .type = STRING };` over one or two lines. The second statement is an assignment using a compound literal.

Comment: I'd say "snap", @DavidC.Rankin.

Comment: Yep, lightning does string twice in the same place `:)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [David C Rankin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3422102/david-c-rankin) and [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) came up with essentially the same answer in the comments at the same time (about 3 seconds apart), here's a Community Wiki composite answer repeating the information:

- No. You cannot allocate with `malloc` and initialize in the same call. You can do:

  ```
  VALUE tmp = {.value = "new", .type = STRING};
  VALUE * val2 = malloc(sizeof(VALUE));  //  (don't forget to check the return)
  *val2 = tmp;
  ```
- No, you can't do the dynamic memory allocation and initialization in one line like that. You'd have to do:

  ```
  VALUE *val2 = malloc(sizeof(*val2));
  *val2 = (VALUE) { .value = "new", .type = STRING };
  ```

  over one or two lines. The second statement is an assignment using a compound literal.

The comment about checking that the `malloc()` succeeds applies to both versions, of course.